# CSS background repeat-x issue

Tags: html, css

i'm beginner in CSS and i try to do somethings but i encountered some problems and here is my problem

i have this peace of CSS code to repeat a background horizontally but i want background to cover just what i wrote not more (there is extra color shown under what i write , i can't upload my photo)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.Container_16 {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:960px;


}

.Container_5 {

float:left;

}
#Title {
font-size:68px;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
.Container_11{

float:left;

color:white;
}
li{
list-style-type:none;
display:inline;
padding-left:15px;
color:white;
font-size:20px;
font-family:sans-serif;
margin-top:30px;
}
nav{
margin-left:150px;
text-align:right;
margin-top:30px;
margin-right:250px;
}

body{
min-width:960px; 
background-image:url("bg.png");
background-repeat:repeat-x;

}

</style>
<body>
<div class="Container_16">
<div class="Container_5" id="Title"><a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Book.me</a>       </div>
<div class="Container_11"><nav>
<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ul>
</nav></div>
</div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? `body` has 100% of device with, so you will see repeated 100% with image.

Comment: When i repeat it color is not cover only the block i want but it goes under it by 80px almost

Answer (score 0):

To apply background image to facebook link only, use this css:

```
#title > a {
    background: url('bg.png') repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are giving the `background` to `body`. I see you have `<div class="Container_16">`
in which you have all your text. So you can set the background to that div only.

**CSS**

```
body{
min-width:960px; 
}
.Container_16 {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:960px;
height:100px;
background-image:url("image.png");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vq5nec4m/)**